# Possible way to add request body and response body information on the actuator's trace endpoint

Tags: java, trace, spring-boot-actuator

How can I catch the params from the request and the response to add on the actuator's trace? I'm using java 8 right now and planning to upgrade to java 17.

I´ve tried some solutions using the filter component from some answers I found on stackeroverflow, but did not work.

Comment: Are you trying to write a custom actuator? Since actuators themselves are endpoints, what do you mean when you say catch params from the request and response?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.